# Give "User" ability to change Images and prices

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making an art website for a family member and what I want to be able to do is give them access to log into the websites and be able to change the pictures of the paintings and the price?

Is this possible? Guessing I would need to make a user first of all.

Comment: You could set them up with a WordPress site, which will give them plenty of editing facilities.

Comment: Yeah I could but I want to keep my website, thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible and yes you need to make an user first
otherwise to who you'll give access to ?

Comment: Alright any advice on how I can do this? its new to me.

Comment: Basically my site is static at the moment, I don't have any databases integrated, is that the only way?

Comment: yes. you can't build it in html, why don't you give them ftp access to edit the html files ?

Comment: I was thinking that... they aren't too tech savy though I guess its an easier. thanks for you help!